# Change standard separator comma for attachments

Tags: windows, filenames, blat

I know that comma will be used to separate files and other stuff with Blat mailer. 
But I must send files with a comma in their filenames and have no possibility to change this circumstance.

Is there a way to change the standard separator? 
Or any other way without changing the filename?

Here my example what I try to do:

```
set SERVER=127.0.0.1:2525
set USER=sendout@ralfbb-test.local
set PW=secret
set FROMNAME=sendout@ralfbb-test.local
set TO=nurmail1@ralfbb-test.local
set SUBJECT="Subject test - attached file!"
set BODY="Oh yes my dear lad!"
set BODYF="c:\Mailbody.txt"
set ATTACH="c:\517-BS24430-210416-NULL-0,750.pdf"

blat -server %SERVER% -f %FROMNAME% -u %USER% -pw %PW% -to %TO% -subject %SUBJECT% -bodyF %BODYF% -attach %ATTACH% -debug -log blat.log
```

Comment: meanwhile some answer my question in an other forum and it works:

Change ATTACH line to this:

set ATTACH="\"c:\517-BS24430-210416-NULL-0,750.pdf\""

The \" tells Blat to take the text verbatim between the two \".

Answer (score 0):

Add a "" when calling the variable:

`"%ATTACH%"`